# Mongodb: Elegant way to turn Aggregation Framework result into POCO

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, aggregation-framework

To make this short and understandable, http://mikaelkoskinen.net/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c/ shows somewhat of what I am trying to accomplish. This "ToDynamic" call breaks on a DateTime value in a return from Aggregation.

With the understanding that we needed a DateTime, I was able to transform this into:

```
public static dynamic ToDynamic(this BsonDocument doc)
    {
        var json = doc.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.TenGen });
        dynamic obj = JToken.Parse(json);
        return obj;
    }
```

This was able to successfully transform this object into a JContainer that I was able to parse with using:

```
returnApp = BsonSerializer.Deserialize(service.apps.ToString(), typeof(MyMongoObject));
```

This was working until we wanted to take in an ObjectId and deserialize that as well. This set of operations broke at the "ToDynamic" call because it was unable to parse the ObjectId being returned.

Has anyone found a continuously successful, elegant way of turning an Aggregation Framework result into a POCO?

Comment: Could you post some concrete MongoDB record examples that don't parse out?

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'json' in your example will contain 10gen specific values , such as ISODate(), BinData() and ObjectId(). I'd suspect JToken.Parse(txt) expects txt to be valid json, not bson.

On the next line the JToken.Parse() will take that json-like-but-actually-proprietary string and try to parse it. You might be better served to use the BsonReader and use JToken.ReadFrom(myBsonReader)

```
using (var reader = new BsonReader(inputStream))
{
    var json = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
}
```